# Get all the Lambda execution IDs from step function invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a step function statemachine where I invoke a lambda execution. I was wondering if it was possible to identify the lambda executions invoked through my statemachine in the statemachine/stepfunction "Execution Event History". I only see links to the lambda and the lambda's cloudwatch log group. But I want to get the precise lambda invocation ID.

I see events like "LambdaFunctionScheduledEventDetails", "LambdaFunctionSucceededEventDetails", ... but no information on the execution ID of the lambda invocation. Is there a programatic way of getting this other than approximating through timestamps?

Comment: If you are looking for aws_request_id then the workaround could be using X-Ray. By enabling X-Ray for Step Functions you can get trace data that has `request_id`

Comment: Ok, but there is no way to get it as part of the event right?

Comment: Not part of the event, there is a separate API call to get X-Ray trace, also if you want to have trace for all execution, then you need to set sampling rule to 100%, unless you have less than 1 execution per seconds that always get samples.

Comment: I see. Thanks!
It would be nice to have it as part of event. Im curious why it is not. I guess the stepfunctions are pretty complex.